# How to print lines between two keywords while keywords in file will repeat and each line-range needs to be stored into separate variable?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file named "animals" which contains following two sections:

```
$ cat animals 
cat 7
dog 83
tiger 2
lion 23
elephant 1
giraffe 23
hippo 2312
#
cat 23
dog 8
tiger 99
lion 299
elephant 2323
giraffe 4
hippo 5
$
```

I would like to print out the lines from "dog" to "elephant" from both sections separately and save the first output to first variable and second output to second variable, i.e. the desired output of first command is:

```
dog 83
tiger 2
lion 23
elephant 1
```

..and desired output of second command is:

```
dog 8
tiger 99
lion 299
elephant 2323
```

I can't use line numbers as sometimes there are additional lines between "dog" line and "elephant" line. I could easily use sed like this:

```
gsed -n '/dog/,/elephant/p' animals
```

or

```
gsed '/dog/,/elephant/!d' animals
```

..but this stores output from both sections. Any suggestions, how to print lines between two keywords while keywords repeat in file and each line-range should be stored into separate variable?

Comment: I'm sure it is doable in bash, but why are you insisting to do this in bash as opposed to a language like python, where this would be a trivial task?

Comment: also, what are you trying to achieve? the way things look here, you're not actually trying to do what you ask, but rather, you're asking how to do "what you think is a solution to what you ***really*** want to achieve. [Classical XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture all the output, then split it using parameter expansion:

```
all=$( sed -n '/dog/,/elephant/p' animals )
first=${all%
dog*}
shopt -s extglob
second=${all#*elephant +([0-9])
}

echo first
echo "$first"
echo second
echo "$second"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `awk`

```
first=$(awk -v n=1 '/dog/ && ++a==n {f=1} f; /elephant/ && f {exit}' file)
second=$(awk -v n=2 '/dog/ && ++a==n {f=1} f; /elephant/ && f {exit}' file)

cat "$first"
dog 83
tiger 2
lion 23
elephant 1

cat "$second"
dog 8
tiger 99
lion 299
elephant 2323
```

Just change then value of `n` to get the section you like

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to split the initial file to multiple files with one section each:

```
cat animals.txt | sed -n '/dog/,/elephant/{/dog/h;/dog/!{x;G;h;};/elephant/{a \
NEXT
p}};' | awk 'BEGIN {RS="\nNEXT\n"};$0 {print $0 > "file" NR}'
```

Then

```
echo "$(cat file1)"
echo "$(cat file2)"
...
```